# How to change coordinates/variables?

Tags: differential-geometry, transformation, classical-mechanics, change-of-variable

I want to model the dynamic behaviour of a point-mass particle moving along a 2D surface given by $h(x_1,x_2)$. I made a question in physics stack exchange, where i found the error in my modelling, and it had to do with the change of coordinates. I provide the link of that post.
( https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/706973/lagrange-equation-of-motions-for-a-particle-moving-in-a-surface-in-the-presence#comment1582721_707239 )

I want to go from the relative coordinates $x_{r1},x_{r2}$ to the global coordinates $x_1,x_2$. This, would allow me to write the langrangian using the local coordinates ($x_{r1},x_{r2}$), which is very easy to write, and then change the variables to the global, fixed, frame of reference.

**What i originally did**: I equated the norms of the vectors ( $x,x_r$ are vectors: $x=(x_1,x_2), x_r = (x_{r1},x_{r2} )$:
$$ || x || = cos(\theta(x)) ||x_r||$$
where:
$$ cos(\theta(x)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + || \nabla h(x) ||^2} }$$
I had written the kinetic term of the lagrangian as $ T = \frac{1}{2}m(x_{r1}^2+x_{r2}^2) = \frac{1}{2}m||x_{r}||^2 $ and then i changed the coordinates and ended up with:
$$ T = \frac{1}{2}m(1 + || \nabla h(x) ||^2)(x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2) = \frac{1}{2}m(1 + || \nabla h(x) ||^2)||x||^2 $$

**However**, as it seems from the accepted answer in the original post, the correct lagrangian has the following kinetic term:
$$ T = \frac{1}{2}m(||x||^2 + || \nabla h(x) \cdot x ||^2)$$

So, how should i do the transformation?

**extra1** in the 1D case, i could do
$$ x_{1} = cos(\theta (x) ) x_{r} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 1+ h'(x_1)^2}} x_r $$
[image: 1D]

**extra2** As it is apparent from the figure of the 1D case, $x_{r,i}$ do not point in the same dirrection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was to transform from curvilinear coordinates to cartesian ones. Wikipedia has [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates) which is very helpful, especially the section "Constructing a covariant basis in one dimension". As in the 1d case, we have the following equation, which relates the infitesimal displacements in each coordinate system:
$$ dx_{r,i} = \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{ \partial h}{\partial x_i}^2 } dx_i $$

(in general we could have $x_{ri} = f(x)$ and not just $x_{ri} = f(x_i)$. In that case, the Jacobian wouldn't be diagonal). This equation, relates the two coordinate systems. If you find the jacobian of this expression, you have the transformation matrix:
$$ x_r  = J x $$
So, i can express the kinetic energy as i did,  and then change the variables according to that transformation rule. BTW, this particular jacobian is:
$$ J = \left [\matrix{ \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{ \partial h}{\partial x_1}^2 } & 0 \cr 0 & \sqrt{ 1+ \frac{ \partial h}{\partial x_2}^2 } } \right ]$$